# php json_decode something not display

Tags: php, json

I use php json_decode something from wikipedia, but something not display.
I have added

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and

```
$data = json_decode(utf8_encode($body));
```

This miss thing is `\/m\u0259\u02c8d\u0292\u028cskju\u02d0lz\/`

Comment: Okay, I think I see the real issue now. You used utf8_[en](http://php.net/utf8_encode)code where a _[de](http://php.net/utf8_decode)code was the goal.

Answer (score 1):

`utf8_decode()` does not look for string expressions like `\u02c8`. You have to decode it the other way round:

```
$data = json_decode($body, 1);  // first; converts \u1234 to strings

array_walk_recursive("utf8_decode_walk", $data);
function utf8_decode_walk($item, $key) {
    return utf8_decode($item);
}                               // replace UTF-8 with Latin-1
```

If it is a nested array, then you'll need array_walk_recursive with a wrapper function however.

Though if you send your output page with `charset="UTF-8"` anyway, you should not need the conversion step.

Comment: @mario, `Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in`

Comment: @yuli chika: that would mean `$data` was invalid. Try to add a `print json_last_error()` in between to find out the reason.

Comment: @mateusza: Yes, indeed. @yuli While that could be changed, it's too deeply nested for using array_map() anyhow. Try using it without UTF-8 decoding, or otherwise array_walk_recursive.

Comment: @mario, only use `$data = json_decode($body);`,I can use foreach get the data, add your code, it show `Call to undefined function json_last_error()`

Comment: @yuli chika: It's available since recently only. So, which PHP version are you using? I'm not sure when support for `\u1234` unicode escapes was added; maybe your version has problems with decoding them. Do you still see any `\u02c8` when writing it out from within the foreach? (In that case ZendFrameworks Json_Service would be the better option to use.)